# Identifying repeating numbers in a array

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

I am dealing with the following problem. I am not looking for anyone to provide me a solution i am looking for some guidance to solving this problem. Here is what i have come up with so far.

I have basically tried to first put a ( around values that repeat. However i am getting a out of bounds error. I would really appreciate it if someone can push me towards the right path for coding a small algorithm that would handle this problem.

My code (in progress)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6,
                3, 1 };

        boolean inRun = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            if (values[i] == values[i + 1] && values[i + 1] < values.length) {
                System.out.print("(");

            }

            System.out.print(values[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider printing the value of 'i' through each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @hoipolloi I didn't get what you meant...can you expand please? sorry.
Am i not already printing the value of i through each iteration

Comment: Your if statement is checking `values[i+1]`.  When you get to the end of your loop, such that `values[i]` is the last element, what will `values[i+1]` be?

Comment: you could turn the array into a string and use the regex `(.)\1+`

Comment: @user: no, you're printing the value in the array. I mean print the actual index e.g. System.out.println(i); , then consider how the index changes as the loop continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate to all the array and if it found a pair then you iterate it again in a while loop until it find the non pair.

**sample:**

```
 int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 1 };

 boolean inRun = false;

 for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

     if (i + 1 < values.length && values[i] == values[i + 1] )
     {
         System.out.print("(");
         while (i + 1 < values.length && values[i] == values[i + 1] )
         {
             System.out.print(values[i++]);
         }
         System.out.print(values[i++]);
         System.out.print(")");
     }
     System.out.print(values[i]);

 }
```

**result:**

```
12(55)31243(2222)36(55)631
```

Comment: awesome. i was thinking something along the lines. can you recommend some source or place where i can tackle more such problems as i want to start breaking down problems like this myself.

Comment: @user2733436 check out http://projecteuler.net/ (currently offline). Different style of problems, but helps you learn programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is here,

```
if (values[i] == values[i + 1] && values[i + 1] < values.length) {
```

Because `i + 1` isn't being tested for less then, or in the correct order -

```
if (i + 1 < values.length && values[i] == values[i + 1]) {
```

Or you could use,

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) { // the length of values - 1 so we can
                                              // get the next value.
```

Comment: In this case it will not print the last value though if i change it like this.

Comment: If you change it like the second example? You could print `values[values.length-1]` after the loop.

Comment: @user2733436 you also need to handle the case when the run ends at the last element separately.